# Difference between pointer and array

Tags: c++, c

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [Difference between char *str=“STRING” and char str[] = “STRING” ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862842/difference-between-char-str-string-and-char-str-string)
>   [C: differences between pointer and array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-pointer-and-array)

Hi,

Can anybody tell me the difference between the statements below?

```
char *p = "This is a test";

char a[] = "This is a test";
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335786/c-differences-between-pointer-and-array ;  the accepted answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782369/similarities-and-differences-between-arrays-and-pointers-through-a-practical-exam is also relevant

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When you declare char p[] you are declaring an array of chars (which is accessible to be both read and written), and this array is initialized to some sequence of characters i.e. "This is test" is copied to the elements in this array.

When you declare char* p, you are declaring a pointer that points directly to some constant literal - not a copy. These can only be read.

Comment: `char *p = "literal"` is ill-formed.

Comment: @SimonRichter not in C89

Answer (score 5):

`a` is an array which means that you can use the `sizeof()` operator on `a` and `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` is equal to the array length.

`p` is a pointer to a constant memory zone.

Answer (score 3):

1 - pointer which points to the read only section of the program containing "This is test\0" string.

2 - memory (13 bytes) which is initialized with contents mentioned above.