# Any difference between "int *path" and "int path[]"?

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Similarities and differences between arrays and pointers through a practical example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782369/similarities-and-differences-between-arrays-and-pointers-through-a-practical-exa)

I used to take them as the same referring to an array name. But now I have encountered an error, that is, when I use `int *path` and try to access the members of the array, the compiler gets a SIGSEGV(Which I never remembered to have happened in the code I have written before), but I it's okay when I use `int path[]`.

So why am I getting a SIGSEGV when using `int *path` ?

Comment: What's the context? As parameter types?

Comment: The compiler doesn't tell you this, your system does.  You probably run out of bounds of your memory you allocated somewhere.

Comment: Code ? Context ? Theoretically, it should not cause any problem.

Comment: is it the **compiler** to get a SIGSEGV? then it is a compiler bug I would say...

Comment: SIGSEGV is the signal error for segmentation fault, which you're getting becuase your pointer isn't referencing the correct location, meaning pointing to a null value or memory location outside of your domain...code samples would help clarify where the pointer is referencing

Comment: since he says it's ok with int path[], I think he is in the situation I guessed in my ans (if this is the case likely SO has already a better expl than mine somewhere, so it's a duplicated Q?)

Comment: This is impossible to answer without an example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just guessing you are trying to write to an array you have declared in the two possible, not equivalent, ways:

```
    int *path = { 4, 5, 3, -1}; /* you're saying this does not work ... when? */
 //  ^ compiler "warning" (error) expected, see edit below
    path[2] = 1;                /* .. when you try this */
```

but

```
    int path[] = { 4, 5, 3, -1};
    path[2] = 1;                 /* but this works */
```

In the first case, path is a pointer to a "static" "list" put somewhere. You have just the pointer to it, can read the content, but likely if you try to write on it, you have segmentation fault. (Likely since those data could be in a memory you can write to even if often it happens you can't, but it depends on the system).

In the second case, an area on the stack is reserved, big enough to hold the data, which then are copied into that area. In this case, you can both read and write to it.

**edit**

as noticed in comments the first example gives warning, you will need a cast (int []) to compile without warning. Then, let us suppose the array is created somewhere where you can't write to, though it could not be the case.

Comment: int *path = { 4, 5, 3, -1}; is ilegal code. For me this only produces warnings (tested with gcc). There is no magic about "readonly" stuff here.

Comment: you're right of course, I've just mimicked the case of char which is quite different, going to fix it though in this way I won't show the issue of the OP... waiting for my mind to be awake

Comment: :-) Yeah, it's a different story with `char *` and `char ... []` Good morning ;-)

Comment: (or OP to give details about his code) (7.15 am when I wrote it - still way far from being awake though:)

Comment: I'm affraid the typecast suggested in the edit above will not solve the problem rather than make it worse: This only removes the warning but still places the value of the first element in `path` so `path` points to 0x4 in your example. After thinking it through I think there is no way to initialize a pointer directly with an array... The only way doing this is `int path[] = { 4, 5, 3, -1};`. But fortunately you can use path then as a pointer too: `int *path2 = { 4, 5, 3, -1};` with no warning. The only thing is that you have to indicate the array end somehow (like 0 termination)

Comment: -1 in my example is the guard, but the end of the array is not the issue here;  (waiting for the OP to be clearer, if I will remember to be back here). You suggestion was correct, and path will point to an area of memory where an array of int is, being 4 just the first element. I suspect OP problem is not end of array, but the fact he's accessing a memory unallocated or read-only (I've tried to "show" the problem briefly maybe failing). But he's giving no details, maybe he has the warning you pointed in my example but simply ignored it, or... I don't know...

Comment: glad it helped though we have not clear yet what it was your actual problem with!

Answer (score 0):

```
int *path = { 4, 5, 3, -1};
```

when you do the above the data will be stroed in read only memory.
so when you try to change any index using that pointer,you will be getting a sigsegv.

But when you do

```
int path[]={...};
```

It will be stored in static memory which is not read only, where you can modify the data in the array

Comment: "int *path = { 4, 5, 3, -1};" is simply ilegal code and produces warnings. This has nothing todo with placing something in readonly memory

Answer (score 0):

- `int path[]`: path points actual array
- `int *path`: path is just a memory pointer. The memory location of `path` might not hold actual array.

I bet you are trying `mktemp()` with `char *path`. I have done many times. :-(
The reason for this SEGV is explained by other people.

Thanks.

Comment: Actually according to Mr. Kernighan and Mr. Ritchie there is no difference between these two. So whatever you did wrong, when "doing this many times" it was not the notation.

Comment: I dump from Expert C Programming: `extern int *x;` vs `extern int y[];`. Two declarations are different. The former declares x to be a pointer to int; the latter declares y to be an array of int of unspecified size. - ANSI C Standard 6.5.4.2

Comment: I dump from "The C programming Language" by Brian W. Kernighan and Dennis M. Ritchie (inventors of 'C'): "In C, there is a strong relationship between pointers and arrays, strong enough that pointers and arrays should be discussed simultaneously. Any operation that can be achieved by array subscripting can also be done with pointers." I'd recommend reading Ch. 5.3, "Pointers and Arrays" for details about the inner workings.