# What's the difference between an array and a pointer in C exactly?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

This question may sound stupid but I'm not really sure about it. I mean, what's the difference between:

```
char* line = (char*) malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN);
```

and

```
char line[MAX_LINE_LEN];
```

exactly? I know the former is a pointer and the latter is an array, but how can the system tell the difference? How is the memory allocated/stored?

Also, why can you delete the memory occupied by `line` when it's declared as a pointer, but not when it's an array? I think that an array is stored somewhere else and the system automatically deallocates its memory when it's out of scope, which doesn't happen when you are dealing with a pointer so you must delete it yourself. Am I wrong?

Comment: This question has eben answered many times, please Look for it

Comment: I don't it's a dup. That one's more about (un)modifiable strings.

Comment: Also, the principal difference between the two lines you listed here is that the second declaration is right, the first one is wrong.

Comment: Please do not close this question with what dtech suggested. The other question is different from this question.

Comment: @nhahtdh Is it worth reopening? I'm happy to cast a vote, even if only to have it closed to a more accurate duplicate.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour: I think it is worth reopening for a good duplicate (if there is not, it is even better of a reason to do so).

Comment: @luserdroog It seems like you'll agree. Care to cast a vote?

Comment: I found a closer [similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782369/similarities-and-differences-between-arrays-and-pointers-through-a-practical-exa). Still not quite a dup.

Comment: It is thoroughly covered in the [clc FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Comment: possible duplicate of [stack pointer difference char pointer and array](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12760229/stack-pointer-difference-char-pointer-and-array)

Comment: @user93353 This question asks more than that question.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour - multiple questions should be asked as multiple questions, if at all.

Comment: @user93353 I just spotted an incredibly popular question, linked to this one [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap). It seems that 1653 people think it's not inappropriate to ask multiple questions in a question.

Answer (score 4):

```
char* line = (char*) malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN);
```

This is poor style; You don't need to cast `malloc` in C. Let's break this up into two sections, because it's easier to describe and compare that way:

`char *line;` declares a pointer to char named `line`. You can assign it to point to an object (or nothing). The `sizeof` an object is the size of it's type, so `sizeof (line)` is `sizeof (char *)`, which varies from system to system. `&line` is the address of a `char *`, which has the type `char **` (pointer to pointer to char). It's storage duration depends upon where it is declared:

- If it's declared outside of any function, it has static storage duration, which lasts for the lifetime of the program. Objects with static storage duration are initialised to `0`, unless an explicit initialisation exists (e.g. in your case). `0` is a `null pointer constant`, indicating that this object would point to *nothing* if it were declared outside of functions without an initialiser.
- If it's declared inside of a block of code, it has automatic storage duration, which lasts until execution reaches the end of that block of code. Objects with automatic storage duration must be explicitly initialised or assigned to before they're used, because their value otherwise is indeterminate.

Your initialisation assigns a value to it, so it won't start off indeterminate regardless. `malloc` returns a pointer to an object that has dynamic storage duration, which means the object that the pointer points to persists until it is explicitly `free`d.

Think of *this* `line` like the postcode on a mail envelope; You can write something in there, and that something will indicate a location where you can find objects (and people). The postcode doesn't tell you anything about the size of the objects (or people).

---

```
char line[MAX_LINE_LEN];
```

This declares an array of `MAX_LINE_LEN` chars.

- If declared outside of any functions, it has static storage duration and the entire array is zero-filled.
- If declared inside a function or block of code, it has automatic storage duration and the values in the array are indeterminate; They need to be initialised (e.g. `char line[MAX_LINE_SIZE] = { 0 };` will initialise all of them) or assigned to (e.g. `line[0] = '\0';` will assign to the first element of the array) before they're used.

The type is `char[MAX_LINE_SIZE]`, so the size will be `sizeof (char[MAX_LINE_SIZE])`, reflected as you can see by the number of elements specified. The address of `&line` in this case is a `char (*)[MAX_LINE_SIZE]` (a pointer to an array of `MAX_LINE_SIZE` chars).

This one can't be reassigned like the one above, so it differs from our postcode example. When an array is used in places where a compiler expects a pointer, the array will be implicitly converted to a pointer to the first element. For example, let us consider:

```
strcpy(line, "Hello, world!");
```

The function prototype `char *strcpy(char *restrict s1, const char *restrict s2);`, tells us that `strcpy` accepts two `char *` (*pointer to char*) arguments. In the example, one of the arguments is a `char[MAX_LINE_LEN]`, and the other is a `char[14]`. Both got converted to a `char *`.

This array-to-pointer conversion explains why `char *line; line = "hello";` is valid, while `char line[MAX_LINE_LEN]; line = "hello";` isn't. You can't change the pointer that results from the conversion.

> I know the former is a pointer and the latter is an array, but how can
>   the system tell the difference?

As previously stated, an array expression is converted to a pointer expression when it's used in places where a pointer is expected. For example, `array` in `array[x]` is converted to `pointer` in `pointer[x]`. What are you asking? Why would it need to know the difference between an array and a pointer?

> I think that an array is stored somewhere else and the system
>   automatically deallocates its memory when it's out of scope,

Yes. I explained the different storage durations earlier.

> which doesn't happen when you are dealing with a pointer so you must
>   delete it yourself. Am I wrong?

Yes. You're confusing the concept of *pointers* with the concept of *storage duration*. `int *p = malloc(sizeof *p);` p is initialised to point to an `int` that has dynamic storage duration. That `int` won't be destroyed until `free(p);` is called. Both of the variables below, however, have automatic storage duration because they're declared within `main`, without any qualifiers such as `static`. `p` points to `i`; `p` is a pointer. Don't `free` p, because it doesn't point to an object that has dynamic storage duration. `free` is only defined to destroy objects that have *dynamic* storage duration.

```
int main(void) {
    int i = 42;
    int *p = &i;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably the best resource for understanding this is the [comp.lang.c FAQ](http://c-faq.com/aryptr/index.html).

Pragmatically, the difference is in the effect of the `sizeof` operator. `sizeof(pointer)` gives you the size of a pointer, whereas `sizeof(array)` gives you ... you guessed it.

When passed as a function argument, an array name decays into a pointer to the first element (losing the `sizeof` information). In a normal expression, it behaves *as if* it decayed to a pointer, because the *array syntax* is defined in terms of the equivalent pointer operations. (In fact early C compilers declared pointers with `identifier[]`.)

```
A[X]
```

is, by definition, exactly equivalent to

```
*(A + X)
```

with the caveat that in `A[X]` exactly one of `A` or `X` ([either one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/381542/in-c-arrays-why-is-this-true-a5-5a)) must be a pointer or array.

Answer (score 1):

```
char* line;
```

Allocates pointer on a stack. It will be automatically freed when the [program counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) will go out of the scope of this declaration.

```
line = (char*) malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN);
```

Dynamically allocates `MAX_LINE_LEN` bytes on the heap. To be precise, you should use `malloc` in that way:

```
line = malloc(MAX_LINE_LEN * sizeof(char));
```

Later you should call `free(line)` to release this heap memory.

`sizeof(line)` will return number of bytes taken by the pointer (usually 4 or 8 bytes).

---

```
char line[MAX_LINE_LEN];
```

Allocates `MAX_LINE_LEN` chars on the stack. It will be automatically freed when the [program counter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Program_counter) will go out of the scope of this declaration.

`sizoef(line)` will return `MAX_LINE_LEN * sizeof(char)` bytes.

Comment: That's not even close to the whole story.

Comment: It's not accurate, either.

Comment: what's the "program counter" ?

Comment: Is there any difference between memory allocated on the heap and on the stack?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836309/stack-memory-vs-heap-memory, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap

Answer (score 1):

Answer is right there, heap and stack issue.

array, pointer, local variables are stack objects, and heap object is using malloc/free method.

Just take a look at [What and where are the stack and heap?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79923/what-and-where-are-the-stack-and-heap) for details.

Comment: ... and a nonsense one at that. You can't state definitively that objects declared with static storage duration go on either the stack or the heap. They might go in a queue, or become registers.

Comment: Ok, I'm NOT sure if it's right to use the concept from C++ (the term object)

Comment: @Daniel Have you read [the C standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf), lately? A mediocre task for you: Count how many times "object" appears in that text.

Comment: @undefined behaviour  OK, I got it. I haven't read the latest standard yet! :) It seems there are many places using object terms.

Comment: @Daniel Don't confuse types with storage durations. It's possible to allocate arrays using `malloc`: `int (*ptr_to_array)[20] = malloc(sizeof *ptr_to_array);` ptr_to_array now points to an array that has dynamic storage duration. `NULL` is a pointer that certainly doesn't fall into the "stack objects" category.

Comment: @undefined behaviour   Firstly, I have checked C89, C99(C89-May 13, 1988: http://flash-gordon.me.uk/ansi.c.txt
C99-2011: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf
C99-2007: http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/WG14/www/docs/n1256.pdf). Yes, you are right, it's OK to use object concept. Secondly, int (*ptr_to_array)[20], IMO, ptr_to_array is a pointer, which points to an array of 20 integer.

Comment: @Daniel Yes... and the array of 20 `int` it points to resides where: *the stack*, or *the heap*?

Comment: @undefined behaviour  if we use malloc, then it's heap.

Comment: @Daniel That's a little more consistent. Good. Is `NULL` an object?

Comment: @undefined behaviour, Well, from my understanding, NULL is an instance of a pointer. And a variable in the program might be in the heap, stack or even registers. As for a block of memory, compiler will assigned to stack(static), and if the programmer want to use dynamic allocation, we can use malloc/free methods.