# uint8 srcBuf[] and uint8 * srcBuf

Tags: c, arrays, pointers

I have written a function and asked some questions here about it. It works very well, I can call it and use it. But something has confused my mind. Here is the function prototype which I just mentioned:

```
void writeToEEPROM( uint8 srcBuf[], uint32 byteCount, int writePtr);
```

I can call this function by sending my array to it, like this:

```
uint8 mysrcBuf[10];

writeToEEPROM(mysrcBuf,10,0);  // This is working.
```

In the function prototype, it gets `*srcBuff` and ,as I know, `*srcBuff` is the value in the address of `srcBuff`. I mean, asteriks(`*`) operand actually reads the value of that address, doesn't it? But I am sending `mysrcBuf` which is the address for the first element of the array.

If i declare the function like below, it still works:

```
void writeToEEPROM( uint8 * srcBuf, uint32 byteCount, int writePtr);
```

Are these statements same?:

`uint8 srcBuf[]` and `uint8 * srcBuf`

It does not warn me or cause problems if I change the declaration and call it with same way.

(Sorry if there is a duplicate of this question. I have searched pointers a lot. But it still confuses me sometimes.)

Comment: Did you search before posting?

Comment: See [difference-between-passing-array-and-array-pointer-into-function-in-c](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5573310/difference-between-passing-array-and-array-pointer-into-function-in-c)

Comment: Related: [Similarities and differences between arrays and pointers through a practical example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1782369).

Comment: @trojanfoe Yes ,as i said, i searched before posting. But some people can have difficulties while trying to find the similar questions; especially if they don't have the deep technical knowledge and language skills to find the "key"words. I didn't know what `decaying` means before, and now i learned it. So i can approve that question as duplicate and people can find that question through my question, right? I can not prove to you how many questions that i searched till here...

Answer (score 1):

In your case,

```
void writeToEEPROM( uint8 srcBuf[], uint32 byteCount, int writePtr);
```

and

```
void writeToEEPROM( uint8 *srcBuf, uint32 byteCount, int writePtr);
```

will be *same*, as when arrays are passed as function arguments, they decay to the address of the first element. So, both the representations will be okay to receive the same.

Comment: Surely it should be `const uint8 *`?

Comment: @trojanfoe Should, but not must, right? :)

Comment: I said "should" didn't I?  You don't see the benefit of `const` and conveying that benefit to the OP?

Comment: Why not `uint8 const *`? {ducks and runs} :-D

Comment: Well then, what if i want to send a char array to call that function. I know that i need to cast the `char` to `uint8` like this: `writeToEEPROM((uint8 *)"ExampleCharArray",10,0);` But why do i need to use asteriks to cast it?

Answer (score -3):

They are the same but `uint8 * srcBuf` is more accurate.